# Php переменные в триггере MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Можно ли в триггере MySql использовать php-переменные? Столкнулся с тем, что нужно написать триггер, которые при изменениях в таблице будет записывать информацию в определенные поля таблицы, т.е. они будут меняться. И можно ли вообще в данной ситуации использовать триггер? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Триггер срабатывает на стороне MySQL-сервера. Он ничего не знает о php. Но решить задачу фиксации изменений с помощью триггера можно. Он знает старые `OLD.field` и новые `NEW.field` значения для записи, которая редактируется в таблице, для которой этот триггер создан.

[Триггеры в MySQL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/)